# Deleting a row which is based on a varchar primary key in php

Tags: php, mysql, varchar, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a particular row in a table in php and I'm trying to use the primary key which happens to be of the type `varchar`, the primary key is `course_Code`

```
course_Code||course_Title||credit_Load||lecturer_id
  csc 450  ||    S.E     ||    3      ||     0
```

`lecturer_id` will always be 0 for all records added because I want to use it as a foreign key, only then would the value be changed from 0 to something else; the problem is when I have only one value in the table and I delete it, the query runs but a new row gets added with only `credit_Load` and `lecturer_id` having values of 0 while the other columns remain empty:

```
course_Code||course_Title||credit_Load||lecturer_id
           ||            ||    0      ||     0
```

This is the code i've written for `firstpage.php`, the value in `$result['course_Code']` is the course code fetched from the database:

```
<a href="processor3.php?coursecode=<?php echo $result['course_Code']; ?>
```

Then `processor3.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['coursecode'])){         
    $course_id = $_GET['coursecode'];
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_Code = '$course_id'");
    header("Location:firstpage.php?succ=2");
}
```

I know I'm using the deprecated way of connecting to mysql in php, but that's not the main issue, I'm trying to teach someone php and he didn't seem to understand pdo bindings very well, so I want us to progress slowly to pdo. I guess I'm a bad teacher.

Comment: Echo the query before executing it, the space in the course code might be getting URL encoded by your browser. E.G " " is `%20` or `+`. Also note that with this is SQL injectable, might as well use `mysql_real_escape_string` until you switch over.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the danger of sql injection, but the app is not going to be live it's just for a small simple project so i didn't bother about security, but i still informed him about the dangers of sql injection and why pdo is better than the old traditional mysql way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terrible, terrible TERRIBLE!!!

```
 $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_Code = '$course_id'");
```

Please never teach anybody to query this way. ALL variables should be escaped, as otherwise there is SQL INJECTION vulnerability.

As for your problem, I suspect 2 possible issues:

1. somewhere without your knowledge a script to add row is called
2. you are using wrong MySQL viewer to confirm contents of the table after deletion.

Are you sure neither of the above is happening?

Comment: you were right!!!...my processor3.php handles many requests and my insert query was not properly nested in one of the numerous if statements....Thanks a mil

Comment: a little harsh on the OP, wouldn't you say?

Comment: sorry, but just two weaks ago I had to solve huge company fiasco when such code was introduced by new tea member. hopefully danindee will teach his students not to code this way from the begining

Comment: Yeah, well given that; I'll have to agree with you on that. We see so many people being taught bad coding habits and keep passing them on. After all, they need to know that this isn't 1995 anymore, but 30 years later and that a lot of water's gone under the bridge since ;-)